# Force trailing slash on laravel app base URL

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I have an application made by Laravel 5.3
Hosted in IIS in a virtual directory like this ( http://example.com/foo )
I have two routes to the base url

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'jobs.index', 'uses' => 'FrontController@index']);
Route::post('/', ['as' => 'jobs.index', 'uses' => 'FrontController@index']);
```

When i use URL::to('/') in a form i always get http://example.com/foo i want to get http://example.com/foo/ because the first throw the 405 - method not allowed error.

any solution to this please?

Comment: And in the form you use POST ?

Comment: how if you try to use another method? like: `'uses' => 'FrontController@store' `

Comment: you might want to do it from IIS heres a stack overflow url https://serverfault.com/questions/669841/using-iis-http-redirect-feature-allow-non-trailing-slash-for-sub-folders

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Route::any(“/“, [“as” => “jobs.index”, 'uses' => 'FrontController@index']);
```